# Storing a function in a header file

Tags: c

I have this structure as a header file in one of my c projects.

```
struct info{

char name[50];
char address[150];
char country[20];
char region[20];
char postalcode[10];
char phonenumber[15];
char paymethod[15];

};
```

But can i store a function in a header file? Cause it'd be easier to maintain the whole program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function and save it in a header file with the extension .h, so that you can use it in times. As example, i will create a function to add two integer values and return the sum whenever the function is being called..

```
int sumOfTwoInteger(int a ,int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

Now all i have to do is save the file with a name and an extension .h, e.g 'myheader.h'
Now put the header file in the same directory where your actual program is.
In the beginning of your actual program add the header file

```
#include"myheader.h"
```

Now you can call that function whenever you want...

```
int sum;
sum = sumOfTwoInteger(10,5);
```

And the sum will be stored in the variable 'sum'

Comment: This works only if your project has only one  .c file that includes the .h file. As soon as you have more than one .c file that include the header file, you'll get "multiple definition" errors during link time.

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate practice is to store the function prototypes (function declarations) in header file. The function implementations go into a ".c" file.

Answer (score 1):

> But can i store a function in a header file? Cause it'd be easier to maintain the whole program.

I assume by *store*, you mean *define*.

Yes, you can define functions in a header file using the `inline` keyword if using C99 or a later version of C.

However, in practice that is good only for small functions.

It's best to declare functions in .h files and define them in .c files for most functions.

Defining functions `inline` can provide performance boost to the program but it also couples the declaration and definition. If the definition needs to be changed, you'll have to re-compile all the .c files that `#include` the .h file. Depending on the size of the project, that can be expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a function in a header file but you shouldn't.

It seems easy to manage a project with "a file for a single operation" style but when project gets bigger, and when you have lots of functionalities, it will be easier to read through header files for definitions.

And if you want to make your code re-usable, header files helps you binary-only distribution of your code in libraries(i.e. you share your function library through a header without exposing your actual code)